# How to edit serialized content in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am wondering if it is at all possible to edit an array that was serialized and stored in mysql directly in my mysql?

I am working with a plugin in WordPress that stores an array in mysql (serialized) but I need to change some of the array's values.  I was hoping to edit the serialized string in the database but whenever I do the plugin is no longer able to read any of the data.

Is there a way I can edit the serialized data directly without breaking how the plugin reads it?

Cheers!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: I know how to unserialize it.  But I want to edit the serialized string directly in mysql.

Comment: That seems like monumentally bad idea.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. "serialize" is a language specific function. Not all languages does the same behavior when serializing array. And tho PHP is so clingy with Mr. MySQL, doesn't mean they have the same functions :)

Comment: Agree with @Difster. If you want to store data in DB and be able to deal with it - use JSON format. MySQL supports a lot of JSON functions since 5.7 release so you can access data without problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unserialize it and then serialize it again. Those are basic php functions.

```
$array = unserialize($serialized_data);
//do stuff to $array

$serealize = serialize($array);
```

Comment: I was thinking that... but the serialized string I get back appears to be different than the string in the database.  So maybe they are storing the array in a different manner that simply serializing it.

Comment: WordPress just uses the PHP serialize/unserialize functions. There's no reason the  plugins shouldn't be able to read it, I've done it before. If you or remove characters, elements etc. it does change the string. But it shouldn't render it unreadable. I should add, that I've done this many times.

Comment: I ended up just writing some shortcode that pulled the serialized string then ran some code to update the required changes and put it back into the database.  That worked.